# Datetime index-based slicing with Dask

Tags: pandas, dask-delayed, dask-dataframe

I have two dataframes: `links` has two datetime columns called `onset` and `offset` and each row is an event. The other dataframe is called `sensors`, is indexed with datetime index of freq 1m, and has ~600 columns, each for a sensor-id. Essentially, for each `links` row, I want to use the onset and offset values as a time range to slice the related rows from `sensors`, aggregate them across rows by getting the mean and then concatenate the single row mean-sensor values to the `links` dataframe horizontally. I have managed to do that with following Pandas code, and it works but I have a lot of data and is extremely slow.

```
def search_sensors(sensors, start_time, stop_time):
    s = sensors[start_time: stop_time]
    s = s.mean()
    return s

# add column names of sensor-ids
links[sensors.columns] = None

for index, row in links.iterrows():
    start_time = row['start_time']
    stop_time = row['stop_time']
    mean_sensors = search_sensors(sensors, start_time, stop_time)
    links.iloc[index, sensors.columns] = mean_sensors.to_list()
```

I have already tried some stuff with Dask but no luck.

1. Using `dask.delayed()` with Pandas, I get a `UserWarning: Large object of size 35.62 MiB detected in task graph:`

```
    mean_sensors_list = []

    for index, row in links.iterrows():
        start_time = row['start_time']
        stop_time = row['stop_time']
        mean_sensors = dask.delayed(search_sensors)(sensors, start_time, stop_time)
        links_list.append(mean_sensors)   # mean_sensors is delayed object containing a pandas.Series of shape (600, nan) 

    results = dask.compute(*mean_sensors_list)
```

2. Using `dask.dataframe()` with the following code is as slow as Pandas, and I don't see any parallelization indications in Dask dashboard.

```
    sensors_dd = dd.from_pandas(sensors_interp, npartitions=1)
    links_dd = dd.from_pandas(links, npartitions=1)

    mean_sensors_list = []

    for index, row in links_dd.iterrows():
        start_time = row['start_time']
        stop_time = row['stop_time']
        mean_sensors = search_sensors(sensors_dd, start_time, stop_time)
        links_list.append(mean_sensors)   # mean_sensors is a dask.Series of shape (600, nan)

    results = dask.compute(*mean_sensors_list)
```

3. Using both 1 and 2, i.e., `mean_sensors = dask.delayed(search_sensors)(sensors_dd, start_time, stop_time)`,  mean_sensors is a delayed object containing a dask.Series of shape (600, nan) but the execution is very slow. The Dashboard shows some parallelization of 3 tasks (search_sensors, finalize, from_pandas) and the 4 workers show very low CPU usage. Additionaly Ubuntu shows a message of Low disk Space when I run it.

Answer (score 0):

New to Dask, and I was not familiar with `map_partitions()`. The solution to the problem was the following:

```
res = links_dd.map_partitions(lambda df: df.apply((lambda row: search_sensors(sensors, row.start_time, row.stop_time)), axis=1)).compute()
```

Extremely fast in my 4-cores laptop.